# Sites keep popping up the cookie information dialog when I am logged in as two users simultaneously on macOS

Tags: support, openid, google-chrome, google-openid, mac

Side Note: This should probably be moved over to AskDifferent, but I don't know how to do that.

The cookie information dialog popping up is **very** annoying. If it were not, I would not continue to spend time trying to resolve it. There are two cases we know of right now:

1. (sporadic) @tripleee gets the same thing in Firefox on iOS but not in Chrome.
2. (100% of the time) I am seeing the problem on Chrome on macOS using two different users, which looks like two separate instances of Chrome running at one time, depending on what Google did to implement the data sharing between separate user windows (two users cannot share a single window or even tabs).

----- Heap (archived so we don't lose the info.)

It appears I may be quite unique in experiencing this since I have not been on Stack Exchange since before they went to the SSO (Single Sign On) mechanism. Please don't vote down my question because you do not understand the situation.

There is a HUGE amount of information that might be needed to reproduce this. I am going to give what I think is the likely cause and hopefully someone out there will be able to track it down.

I believe the problem is caused by the fact that I am logged on as two different Google Profiles on Chrome.

I am logged into two Google Profiles.
I am running Chrome Version 114.0.5735.106 (Official Build) (arm64).
I am running Chrome on macOS 13.4 (22F66).

**This appears to be an interaction between OpenID and Chrome, resulting from the use of two different Google Profiles.**

I am perfectly happy just not logging onto two Google Account IDs at one time. However, I do not know how I am going to get my system back to the place where I can use Stack Overflow's sites without having the darn pop-up pop-up.

Comment: SSO does not like you trying to use several credentials at the same time. Choose one or isolate more.

Comment: SSO = [single sign-on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on)

Comment: It is interesting that I am a new contributor. I've been around for many, many years. The problem above is real. The solution might be to not try to log into two Google Accounts at one time. I'll take that as an answer.

BTW, I signed the Open Letter to Stack Overflow, Inc.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem, but I don't use Chrome, and don't have multiple profiles. In Firefox on IOS, I get the cookie dialog probably several times per day. I am also using Chrome on my desktop computer, and don't get the cookie dialog often there.

Comment: @ToddB. "New contributor" just means you haven't posted on this particular SE site before. It's not meant to imply that you're new to SE entirely, though I can see how it could be interpreted that way.

Comment: @Todd, is your actual user (in the "OS login" sense) different between your Chrome windows, or are you just authenticating twice with Google under the same user?

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title. Instead press the checkmark next to an answer to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem from running iOS 12/Safari on an iPad. But it only happens on stacks I haven't created an account on.

(Newsflash, developers: people may replace their phones every 2 years, but they don't replace their *tablets* every 2 years. The tablet population is concealed amongst the phones.)

Comment: Me currently holding an iPhone 6S suggests that people don't even replace their phones every 2 years.

Answer (score 1):

The answers here were very useful and I think this question should remain visible for others to so the answers that were given to my question.

My problem came about because I was doing things most people do not do. I solved it by identifying what I was doing that was off of the mainstream use case and carefully bringing myself toward it. Once I got close enough to it, the mechanisms that had been put in place to fix the common cases started to help me out.

I am now not seeing the pop-ups, and I'm not sure how the bad credentials got cleared from my system. But they are gone.

As coherence latencies continue to drop these problems will likely be less serious. Keep your worldwide credentials in a single place so you can keep track of them. Of course, that also makes them easier to steal, but I think the benefits outweigh the risks now.

Thank you to everyone who helped me. I learned a lot about issues outside of my specialties and it was great.

Cheers!
Todd